# Java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space [Ubuntu]

Tags: java, java-8, jvm, sap-commerce-cloud

i am trying to run my code and i got this error on my console

```
 [java] Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

i run Jconsole on jdk folder the max heap 1.9m ,how can i change it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for hybris, you need to update tomcat.generaloptions property to adjust Xmx value. For instance, via local.properties.
-Xmx2G is a default value.

```
tomcat.generaloptions=-Xmx4G -ea -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dorg.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperManager.mbean=true -Djava.endorsed.dirs="%CATALINA_HOME%/lib/endorsed" -Dcatalina.base=%CATALINA_BASE% -Dcatalina.home=%CATALINA_HOME% -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8  -Djava.util.logging.config.file=jdk_logging.properties -Djava.io.tmpdir="${HYBRIS_TEMP_DIR}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the max heap size using the `-Xmx size` command line argument.
By default it's 64mb. The 1.9m you see seems strange.

Here is the Oracle doc for the java command:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html

Specifically:

**-Xmxsize**

```
Specifies the maximum size (in bytes) of the memory allocation pool in bytes. This value must be a multiple of 1024 and greater than 2 MB. Append the letter k or K to indicate kilobytes, m or M to indicate megabytes, g or G to indicate gigabytes. The default value is chosen at runtime based on system configuration. For server deployments, -Xms and -Xmx are often set to the same value. See the section "Ergonomics" in Java SE HotSpot Virtual Machine Garbage Collection Tuning Guide at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/index.html.

The following examples show how to set the maximum allowed size of allocated memory to 80 MB using various units:

-Xmx83886080
-Xmx81920k
-Xmx80m
The -Xmx option is equivalent to -XX:MaxHeapSize.
```

Comment: i tried used java -Xmx 4064 i got 
`Invalid maximum heap size: -Xmx
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.`

Comment: Updated the answer with a link to the documentation and actual doc for `-Xmx` usage.